# Oracle SQL trick

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to do something like below in oracle SQL in the where clause of a SQL query

$p="All" then buildingname in(Select buildingname from Building)
else buildingname="$p"

The issue is I cant parse this $p variable i.e. I cant check what it contains

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: From what language are you coming, what do you mean with $p. Can you post some more code?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you just want an `OR` condition,

```
SELECT *
  FROM sometable
 WHERE (    :bind_variable = 'All' 
        AND buildingname IN (SELECT buildingname
                              FROM building))
     OR buildingname = :bind_variable
```

Comment: The problem is I cant parse the bind variable It means I cant check it containts i.e. I cant do like :bind_variable = 'All'

Comment: @ShitalBumb - There is no need to parse the bind variable.  Just pass the bind variable in to the SQL statement (you'll need to pass it in twice).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an OR in your subquery, so it either selects the building select or all of them if $p is 'All'

```
buildingname in (Select buildingname from Building WHERE buildingname = $p OR $p = 'All')
```

Comment: I can't do like this "$p = 'All" due to some constraint

Answer (score 0):

If your variable within the string is replaced by whatever it contains (hence it is not a bind variable but just a variable from a language like PERL or PHP and used within the select string you are building):

```
$selectstring = "SELECT *
  FROM sometable
 WHERE (    '$p' = 'All' 
        AND buildingname IN (SELECT buildingname
                              FROM building))
     OR (   '$p' <> 'All' AND buildingname = '$p'"
```

Become aware of the danger of SQL injection. Bind variables are better. Anyhow the statement for variable $p containing the value 'All' would be

```
SELECT *
  FROM sometable
 WHERE (    'All' = 'All' 
        AND buildingname IN (SELECT buildingname
                              FROM building))
     OR (   'All' <> 'All' AND buildingname = 'All')
```

While you would have a selectstring for variable $p containing 'XYZ' of

```
SELECT *
  FROM sometable
 WHERE (    'XYZ' = 'All' 
        AND buildingname IN (SELECT buildingname
                              FROM building))
     OR (   'XYZ' <> 'All' AND buildingname = 'XYZ')
```

But honestly then you could also do something like

```
if ($p eq 'All') {
...   one select
} else {
...   another select
}
```